# CakePHP login and redirect

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am trying to create an API for my web app that allows a mobile app to update my database.
I have the code in my controller that is meant to be executed, for example:

```
www.mysite.com/projects/doSomething
```

the doSomething function performs some code based on the information sent from the mobile app via a POST request.

The problem is that I want to make this as secure as possible, so I created a user for the mobile app.

How do I send the login information via the POST request, login the user and perform the doSomething function?
P.S. I am using the cakePHP Auth feature

Comment: It depends on the type of mobile app and language you are using. Each language will have it's own code to do a `POST` request to your web application.

Comment: You make a valid comment Hoff, however I was look more for help on how cakePHP will handle the post request. ATM if a user is not logged in they get redirect to the login page. How to I handle the automatic login on cakePHP side?

Comment: You have to do a find based on the credentials provided through the POST request, then when you find the user you can log them in manually using the code from [this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#manually-logging-users-in) of the manual.

Comment: Thanks Hoff! can you post your last comment as an answer so that I can maker it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a find based on the credentials provided through the POST request, then when you find the user you can log them in manually using the code from [this section](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#manually-logging-users-in) of the manual, e.g.:

```
public function register() {
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        $id = $this->User->id;
        $this->request->data['User'] = array_merge($this->request->data['User'], array('id' => $id));
        $this->Auth->login($this->request->data['User']); // logging the newly registered user here
        $this->redirect('/users/home');
    }
}
```